# C# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, methods, properties

I'm getting an error on a site i have developed, it works locally but i've just published it to the server (vidahost) - all I'm trying to do is render the time/date the page was created on. Always done it this way and never had any issues before. I am using Umbraco 7.3

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:

'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params string[])'
```

Stack error;

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params string[])'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params string[])'

Source Error: 


Line 25:             <span class="date">
Line 26:                 <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
Line 27:                     @CurrentPage.CreateDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
Line 28:             </span> 
Line 29:             <span class="author">

Source File: \\sambal\sites\liquidthinker.com\public_html\Views\Article.cshtml    Line: 27 

Stack Trace: 


[RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params int[])' and 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.TypedMedia(params string[])']
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , UmbracoHelper , Object ) +248
   ASP._Page_Views_Article_cshtml.Execute() in \\sambal\sites\liquidthinker.com\public_html\Views\Article.cshtml:27
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +126
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +110
   Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +140
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +380
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +109
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +890
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

Here is the MVC View;

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Root.cshtml";
}

<!-- Article Template -->
<section class="article">

    <div class="medium-8 large-8 columns noPaddingLeft border-right left-side-content">

        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentPage.customTitle))
        {
            <h1 class="pageTitle">
                @CurrentPage.customTitle
            </h1>
        }
        else
        {
            <h1 class="pageTitle">
                @CurrentPage.Name
            </h1>
        }

        <div class="blogPostInfo large-12 columns noPadding">
            <span class="date">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    @CurrentPage.CreateDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
            </span> 
            <span class="author">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    Damian Hughes
            </span>
            <span class="comments">
                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
                    <a href="@CurrentPage.Url#disqus_thread">0 comments</a>
            </span>                        
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>


        <div class="fullWidthImage large-12">
            <img class="img-thumbnail full" src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(CurrentPage.blogFullImage).Url" alt="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(CurrentPage.blogFullImage).Name" />            
        </div>


        <div class="blogContent">
            @CurrentPage.blogContent
        </div>

        <div class="socialShare large-12">
            <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
            <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="disqusContainer large-12 columns noPadding">
            <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
                <script>
                    /**
                     *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
                     *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
                     */
                    /*
                    var disqus_config = function () {
                        this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
                        this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
                    };
                    */
                    (function() {  // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
                        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

                        s.src = '//liquidthinker.disqus.com/embed.js';

                        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
                        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
                    })();
                </script>
                <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="medium-4 large-4 columns" id="booksSideMenu">
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro("BooksRightSideMenu")
    </div>

</section>
```

Can't quite see why it would error, what am I missing?

Comment: looks like cant differentiate what you're sending to the Date function between a String and an Int, try casting it (String), doesn't have much to do with MVC though lol

Comment: Not Date sorry typemedia(string) and typemedia(int)  need a cast somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with the date, it's with the call to Umbraco.TypedMedia afterwards.

I expect your property is misnamed, so it's not actually "blogFullImage", or there is no media assigned in that property in your content.

Comment: you are correct, the property is not misnamed, it just isn't populated with an image. I'll have to wrap a if else statement so if it isn't populated just render a placeholder image instead. Code needs to be a little more stricter if it isn't a mandatory field, Doh!